# Persisting class instance in other class while populating the UIProgressView

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsurlsession

I have been using **NSURLSession** to download files and storing them in directory and everything is working fine using objective C and XCode 7.3 . I use an **UIProgressView** to show the progress of the download session. But when I try to modularise the code and separate the **NSURLSessionDelegate** methods from the **UIViewController** class , I am unable to use it .

**Problem Description** :

**Class A** : **UIViewController** class which has a table view and a progress View .

**Class B** : **NSObject** class which has a method to start the download session (Class A's instance is passed as a parameter to this class's method)

**Class C** : NSObject class which implements the **NSURLSessionDelegate**  methods and need to populate the progressView in Class A using **SetProgress:** (Unable to do so as I am unable to pass the Class A's instance to Class C and can only create a new instance which isn't going to help)

When I put all the code in one class , it works like charm ! And I tried using protocol but was still unable to do so . So , any help on the same would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Edit 1 : Class C code :

```
-(void) setDelegateForProgressView :(id) delegate {
self.docCatalogInstancePersist = delegate;
}
- (void)URLSession:(NSURLSession *)session downloadTask:(NSURLSessionDownloadTask *)downloadTask didWriteData:(int64_t)bytesWritten totalBytesWritten:(int64_t)totalBytesWritten totalBytesExpectedToWrite:(int64_t)totalBytesExpectedToWrite{
NSString *downloadInProgress = ENABLED;
self.docCatalogInstancePersist.progressView.hidden= NO;

[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:downloadInProgress forKey:@"downloadInProgress"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    [self.docCatalogInstancePersist.progressView setProgress:(double)totalBytesWritten/(double)totalBytesExpectedToWrite
                                             animated:YES];    });


}
```

Comment: can you show code of CLASS C ?

Comment: Edited @PiyushPatel

Comment: It is nil . Because I cannot call the NSURLSessiondelegate methods and by the time they access the selg.docCatalogInstancePersist , the memory releases the object as I call the SetDelegateForProgressView from the StartDownload method in Class B

Comment: So in this case your class B has the instance A and C?

Comment: Correct ! I set the NSURLSession delegate using Class C instance and carry forward the Class A instance in Class B

Comment: So which object is being released when you call setDelegateForProgressView? Class A's instance?

Comment: Correct ! which is Self.doccatalogInstancePersist (Class A) in Class C

Comment: How could this be released? If Class B has this A and C's instance with property then it should be there. Did you get this A and C's instance variable with property in B? I mean for example @property (nonatomic, strong)